# Currency textbox masking

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedtextbox

i want to define data masking for my currency textboxes , so i defined a class bo-money and wrote a function like below

```
  $('.bo-money').keyup(function (arg) {
        this.value = bo_Controller.commafy(this.value);});
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  commafy: function (num) {
    num = num.toString().replace(/\,/g, '') + '';
    return num.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
```

now the values will be save at dB with comma , how do i save them without this format and just numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save **only** numbers, you can just alter your regex to be

```
num.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
```

Comment: If this answered your question and the regex was the issue, then you might find a site like https://regex101.com helpful.

Comment: So i should change 'code' num = num.toString().replace(/\,/g, '') + '';  with your code?

Comment: Yes, if the goal is to remove any non-number from your string, you can change

    num.toString().replace(/\,/g, '') + '';

to 

    num.toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); + '';

Comment: no i want them , but i want to post them without non-numbers , but show them